# How do I link my WIX Project Linker to a resource path that contains spaces?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, installation, wix, wix3.6

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811035/spaces-in-my-wix-source-path) point toward an answer, but none of the answers work in Visual Studio 2010.

The latest version of WIX doesn't work out of the box as it's supposed to when wiring up to a project (specifically a Web Project). As such, I want to link to the $(SolutionDir) macro like this:

```
-b $(SolutionDir)\ChildPath\
```

However, the Solution Directory has a space in it. For example:

```
C:\Some Path\ChildPath\
```

This throws the error:

```
The system cannot find the file 'Path\ChildPath\' with type 'Source'.
```

Notice everything after the space is what comes through in the error. Obviously characteristic of using a path in a command line command without wrapping in quotes. However, if you wrap in quotes, the linker can't interpret the second quote and give another verbose error (it's so lame I won't post). You can't even do this or light.exe takes a dump:

```
-b "C:\Some Path\ChildPath\"
```

Basically, there's no intuitive way to wire in a -b switch in the linker if there's a space in the path anywhere. light.exe can handle it neither from the command line nor from anywhere else. One more thing: It does say you should be able to double-whack the path after the space, but that doesn't work either:

```
-b C:\Some Path\\ChildPath\
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I worked on this quite a bit and couldn't get anything to work. I had to back up and punt by just removing the space from my local path and re-mapping my TFS solutions. Totally sux.

Comment: Don't use a trailing slash and you should be fine, and then in your WiX source use "SourceDir\file.xxx"

Comment: Tried that already. No go.  :(